# Get a user with posts

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am trying to get a user with his posts in laravel, so far I have tried to use the following line

```
User::findOrFail($user_id)->with('posts')->first();
```

But I am getting the first user on the table regardless of what the user ID specified is.

I have tried to dd the user_id and it's working fine, (getting the user_id from the route).

So far the result I am getting is if the user id is x and the first user in the table has an id of 1 I get the info of user id 1 and his posts.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your methods in the wrong order.

1. `findOrFail` executes the query immediately, which returns the `User` record for `$user_id`.
2. Chaining that to `->with()` **will start a new query.**
3. Finally, calling `->first()` returns the first `User` from the database.

Adjust your query as such:

```php
User::with('posts')->findOrFail($user_id);
```

Comment: Thank I didn't know that the order mattered :) and thanks for the clarification!

Comment: No worries! In a lot of cases, order actually doesn't matter, but for certain methods, like `->find()`, `->first()`, `->get()`, etc., it really does. Closures like those should be called as the last method of your query chain.  There are some exceptions/caveats, but that's the general rule.

Answer (score 0):

`findOrFail`and `first` will give you the User Object but you have to decide witch function you will use.

If you use Routemodel Binding then you can use:
`User::with('posts')->first();` or `User::load('posts');`

If you dont use routemodel Binding you can use findOrFail like that:
`User::with('posts')->findOrFail($user_id);`